# Install instructions for SharePoint 2010 SP1

Tags: 2010, installation

I have started the install process for SharePoint 2010 SP1.  The instructions I found on Microsoft stated that I should download the package and then start it.

However it appears that the install package did **not** stop OWSTimer or the IIS sites.  This has caused a lot of errors in my application event log and a steady stream of Visual Studio Debug Consoles starting.

So did I do something wrong with the SP1 install?

Comment: Check the upgrade logs and the ULS logs. Then post any errors here so that we might be able to help you.

Comment: I got an LDAP container error, plus a bunch of postsetup errors, retrying now

Comment: Did you run the config wizard after installing?

Comment: The errors occured during the SP1 install.  I did the required reboot after install.  I am checking now to see if everything is running properly.  I have not run the config wizard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have published an article describing the steps required to install and configure SharePoint Server 2010 SP1 on the existing farm with screen shots.  See below URL for detail:

[How to install and configure SharePoint Server 2010 SP1 on the existing SP 2010 Farm](http://www.sp-blogs.com/blogs/adnan/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=8)

Answer (score 0):

My install says all is updated except Language pack. Installation itself works fine. No problems during install itself. Did follow all the steps, Foundation update, foundation Languagepack (not needed), server update, server language pack update (I used the LP including the project server files, but used the server only lp update, so that didn+t get updated